# Permissions check postgresql function

Tags: postgresql

I have a function written in plpgsql that checks if user have permissions:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_permission(acc_id integer, permissions text[]) RETURNS boolean AS $$
        BEGIN
          SELECT DISTINCT p.name FROM person_role pr
          JOIN role_permission rp ON pr.role_id = rp.role_id
          JOIN permission p ON rp.permission_id = p.permission_id
          WHERE account_id = acc_id ;
          
          -- check
        END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

How can i check that select includes all permissions from **permissions text[]** argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [unnest](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS) the array into a result set and from it [subtract](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-union.html) the role names from your result:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_permission(acc_id integer, permissions text[]) RETURNS boolean AS $$
  SELECT NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT unnest(permissions)
    EXCEPT
      SELECT DISTINCT p.name
      FROM person_role pr
      JOIN role_permission rp ON pr.role_id = rp.role_id
      JOIN permission p ON rp.permission_id = p.permission_id
      WHERE pr.account_id = acc_id
  );
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

It might however better express the intent to use a [boolean aggregate](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) over the `permission` table and a subquery:

```
SELECT bool_and(EXISTS(
  SELECT *
  FROM person_role pr
  JOIN role_permission rp ON pr.role_id = rp.role_id
  WHERE rp.permission_id = p.permission_id
    AND pr.account_id = acc_id
))
FROM permission p
WHERE p.name = ANY permissions -- or JOIN (SELECT unnest(permissions) AS name) USING (name)
```

<sup>Notice this will return `NULL` instead of `TRUE` when the `permissions` array is empty.</sup>